# Can I say "It will be my pleasure to help you" in an email reply?

Tags: american-english

If someone asked for my help via email, can I say:

> It will be my pleasure to help you.

Comment: To my ears, it *would* be my pleasure to help you sounds better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it indeed is perfectly OK to say "It will be my pleasure to help you," you might also want to consider:

> *I will be more than happy/pleased to help you*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly okay to use that senetence.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, could you elaborate a little for the OP and future visitors?